Inconsistent matching of width media query at different zoom levels for Iframed page
Given the following inner page:
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style>
div{
    background-color: blue;
}

@media (max-width: 767px)
{
    .stuff{
        background-color: red;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="stuff">some content</div>
</body>
</html>

And the following outer page (assuming inner page is saved as inner-page.html):
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    width: 767px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe class="container" src="inner-page.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

when viewing the outer page on a large monitor (1920x1080) at 100% zoom, the content has a red background as expected. However zooming in, the background fluctuates between red and blue.
For example on Firefox:
at 100% - red
at 110% - blue
at 120% - red
at 133% - blue
at 150% - blue
at 170% - blue
at 200% - red

The result of window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches (from the context of the inner-page) also varies at the different zoom levels, consistent with the above results.

What is the width value in the media query compared against exactly? My understanding was CSS pixels and not device pixels. Is there a JS property that refers to this value? It doesn't seem to be any of the following:

window.innerWidth
screen.width
window.document.documentElement.offsetWidth
window.document.documentElement.clientWidth


What is the cause of the inconsistent matching? I would have expected the media query to match at all zoom levels.


I have found that lowering the iframe width by one pixel compared to the media query results in the media query consistently being matched at various zoom levels.
.container {
    width: 766px;
}

Therefore, my guess is that zoom changes might involve fractional values for width and height. And these may be getting rounded up or down for media query comparisons.
